# How to calculate the total revenue of a day using vb.net?

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

Currently I'm developing a vb.net program which is based on 'Movie Ticket Purchasing System'. Right now I'm trying to develop a code where, once the cinema is closed for the day, the system will calculate the total amount of collections in both movie ticket purchases and snack/drink purchases.

Let's say that:

TicketPrice - total price of movie tickets purchased

SnackPrice - total price of snacks/drinks purchased

TotalCinemaPrice - TicketPrice  + SnackPrice

So, "TotalDayRevenue", for example, will be the total number of tickets, snacks and drinks sold throughout the day.

Also, I know that 'For Loop' will be used in order to get this kind of value, but I don't know how to efficiently, and properly write the code.

Help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency right now, just focus on doing whatever you need to do to get your answer. For loop is correct. We will not write the code for you, so you will need to take a stab at it yourself. Once you have some code and are having trouble with a line or something, you can update your question and we can help.

Comment: Where and how is your data stored?

Comment: What is your question? How to multiply and add values? Something else? Please be specific.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I wanna add values once every transaction is completed. Sorry for the misinterpreted question, my English is bad.

Comment: So then, add them values. It's unclear, which part of adding values you seem to be having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable to store the total day revenue:

```
double totalAmount = 0;
```

Then get the amount of tickets and snacks you've sold and multiply that with the price. Then add it to the total day revenue:

```
totalAmount += amountOfTicketsSold * priceForOneTicket;
totalAmount += amountOfSnacksSold * priceForOneSnack;
```

Kind regards